# Css keyframes + opacity:0 brings div back when finished

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I am using keyframes to blur and fade out a div when the document is clicked and I can't figure out why after the animation is finished, the div is visible again...

**CSS**

```
#red{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    margin:50px;
    background:red;
}
.blur{
    -webkit-animation: fadeout linear 2.5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
   0% {    -webkit-filter: opacity(100%) blur(0px);}
  50% { -webkit-filter: opacity(100%)  blur(10px);}
 100% {  -webkit-filter: opacity(0%) blur(20px);}
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $('#red').addClass('blur');
});
```

Is there a better way of doing this?
Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/sczh6L7a/)

Comment: You need to use `animation-fill-mode` to retain the state of the animation.

Comment: Remove `webkit` prefix. Or add the normal version after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use

`animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to maintain the final state at the end of a CSS animation.